# how to find what amount of memory is used in RAM in java

Tags: java

i want the code which should print the memory used in the following print method

```
import java.*.*;
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println('The memory used is');
    }
```

Comment: 'memory used' is a very broad concept. Memory used by the JVM, Memory allocated to the JVM, memory used overall in the system? All of these would be valid interpretations.

Comment: Look into java.lang.management, everything that has "Memory" in its class name and try whatever you think will answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code

```
float mb = 1024*1024; 
    //Getting the runtime reference from system
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    System.out.println("##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####");

    //Print used memory
    System.out.println("Used Memory:"+ (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);

    //Print free memory
    System.out.println("Free Memory:"+ runtime.freeMemory() / mb);

    //Print total available memory
    System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb);

    //Print Maximum available memory
    System.out.println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / mb);
```

Comment: Accepting the answer would help

Comment: will vote ;) keep it up

Answer (score 1):

There are methods to calculate the

> `**total memory and free-memory**`

at the runtime.

```
class temp
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();


    System.out.println(rt.totalMemory());
    System.out.println(rt.freeMemory());
    System.out.println(rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory());
    }}
```